# SWF Movie does not appear when test the flash project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I was trying to test my flash project. As I pressed ctrl + enter, there was no pop up windows for flash player appeared. My other projects work well.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: that's too little information to go on. Surely something must happen that you are not describing.

Answer (score 0):

**there could be many problems and solutions, these are 6 :**

1- Check if there is an error in your Compiler Errors window.

2- Restart your pc.

3- If you use (ane) for different platform it won't show preview in many cases.

4- Reinstall your flash or change your flash player or Air version.

5- You might use "NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit()" somewhere if you have adobe Air  project.

6- Start a new project and  test it if it shows a preview window copy your stuff from the old one .

Comment: thank you for your solutions. There was no error in Compile Errors window. So i was clueless. Btw, thank you for your helps!